# Can't Install Nginx on Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx

I've just created an Ubuntu server. I've tried to install Nginx but I've gotten error.

```
root@scw-eefca0:~# sudo apt-get install nginx
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
nginx is already the newest version (1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.4).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up nginx-core (1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.4) ...
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript nginx, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package nginx-core (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nginx:
 nginx depends on nginx-core (>= 1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.4) | nginx-full (>= 1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.4) | nginx-light (>= 1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.4) | nginx-extras (>= 1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.4); however:
  Package nginx-core is not configured yet.
  Package nginx-full is not installed.
  Package nginx-light is not installed.
  Package nginx-extras is not installed.
 nginx depends on nginx-core (<< 1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.4.1~) | nginx-full (<< 1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.4.1~) | nginx-light (<< 1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.4.1~) | nginx-extras (<< 1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.4.1~); however:
  Package nginx-core is not configured yet.
  Package nginx-full is not installed.
  Package nginx-light is not installed.
  Package nginx-extras is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package nginx (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nginx-core
 nginx
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Edit:

`systemctl status nginx.service` output:

```
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2017-01-23 13:40:38 UTC; 10min ago
  Process: 12375 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jan 23 13:40:38 scw-eefca0 systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Jan 23 13:40:38 scw-eefca0 nginx[12375]: nginx: [emerg] socket() [::]:80 failed (97: Address family not supported by protocol)
Jan 23 13:40:38 scw-eefca0 nginx[12375]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Jan 23 13:40:38 scw-eefca0 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jan 23 13:40:38 scw-eefca0 systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Jan 23 13:40:38 scw-eefca0 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 23 13:40:38 scw-eefca0 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

It's a totally new server and I didn't configure anything except updating apt-get.

Comment: Whats the output of `systemctl status nginx.service`

Comment: I've just added.

Comment: I think the problem may be in your config file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf. What the output of `nginx -t` command?

Comment: Do an `apt-get purge nginx`, `apt-get dist-upgrade` and `apt-get install nginx` again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
nginx: [emerg] socket() [::]:80 failed (97: Address family not supported by protocol)
```

Nginx tries to start, and connect to [::]:80, but can't. Probably because IPv6 is disabled on the machine. Either enable IPv6 or change the nginx configuration. Search for this line in the config file `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`:

```
listen [::]:80 default_server;
```

and comment it out:

```
# listen [::]:80 default_server;
```

restart nginx:

```
systemctl nginx restart
```

or, if this gives error that it is not running:

```
systemctl nginx start
```

Then run the install commands again.